# Web Facebook login using angular 4 : Window not defined in script

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use javascript SDK for facebook login,
I am using the below script with angular 4, 
but I am getting an error saying that window is not defined?
Could you please help me integrate Facebook graph API using angular 4?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else {
  // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
}
}

 // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
 // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : '{your-app-id}',
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                      // the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
  version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
});

// Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
// FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
// person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
// the callback you provide.  They can be:
//
// 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
// 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
// 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
//    your app or not.
//
// These three cases are handled in the callback function.

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
 });

 };

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
 });
}
</script>

<!--
Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
the FB.login() function when clicked.
 -->

 <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" 
onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

 <div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: removed duplicate paragraph, some typos and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I think for facebook integration you can use the npm module "angular4-oauth-login" instead of graph api.

The above plugin give you the integration for google as well.
I have tried the above module and found very easy to understand and implement.

Hope this will help for you. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid error *window is not defined* is using inline definition:

```
(<any>window).fbAsyncInit = function() {
```

Other way is definitions like this:

```
declare var window: any;
declare var FB: any;
```